# Intellij 7.0.3 jsp tag namespace

Tags: jsp, tags, intellij-idea, namespaces

I am declaring a namespace and binding it in a jsp file.  i then include this JSP file in other files.  however, the JSP file that contains this include complains that the namespace is not bound.  Is there a way I can get intellij to intelligently understand that there is a file that is included and the namespace is bound in that file?

Here is the include chain

-Files that are not showing the namespace.

-/common/include-jstl.jsp

-/w/common/include-jstl.jsp is a file that is in an included jar and this is the file has the c name space defined.